# Server aborts on trying to login using Openid using Omniauth, Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid, omniauth

I am using omniauth for my Rails 3 / Ruby 1.9 app and it is working well for Twitter and Facebook. However, I am trying to add Google OpenId and I am facing an issue.

I have the following code in `initializers/omniauth.rb`for Google OpenId:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  require 'openid/store/filesystem'
  provider :openid, 
    OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('./tmp'), 
    :name => 'google', 
    :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
```

When I go to http://localhost:3000/auth/google, I get the following error in terminal and the server quits. I am not sure if using a server certificate will solve the issue. The same error occurs for any openid service, so this issue is not restricted to Google. Thanks.

```
WARNING: making https request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud without verifying server certificate; no CA path was specified.
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60: [BUG] cfp consistency error - call0
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.1.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0062 p:---- s:0352 b:0352 l:000200 d:000200 CFUNC  :next
c:0061 p:---- s:0350 b:0350 l:000343 d:000349 IFUNC 
c:0060 p:---- s:0348 b:0348 l:000347 d:000347 CFUNC  :bytes
c:0059 p:---- s:0346 b:0346 l:000345 d:000345 CFUNC  :each
c:0058 p:---- s:0344 b:0344 l:000343 d:000343 CFUNC  :zip
c:0057 p:0105 s:0340 b:0340 l:000339 d:000339 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60
c:0056 p:0069 s:0333 b:0333 l:000332 d:000332 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:40
c:0055 p:0124 s:0324 b:0324 l:000323 d:000323 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:45
c:0054 p:0320 s:0316 b:0316 l:000315 d:000315 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:331
c:0053 p:0059 s:0305 b:0305 l:000304 d:000304 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:196
c:0052 p:0035 s:0296 b:0296 l:000295 d:000295 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:130
c:0051 p:0074 s:0289 b:0289 l:000288 d:000288 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:118
c:0050 p:0019 s:0285 b:0285 l:000284 d:000284 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer.rb:243
c:0049 p:0103 s:0277 b:0277 l:000276 d:000276 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer.rb:228
c:0048 p:0152 s:0270 b:0270 l:000269 d:000269 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-openid-1.3.1/lib/rack/openid.rb:123
c:0047 p:0138 s:0256 b:0256 l:000255 d:000255 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-openid-1.3.1/lib/rack/openid.rb:102
c:0046 p:0048 s:0247 b:0247 l:000246 d:000246 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-openid-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/open_id.rb:70
c:0045 p:0020 s:0242 b:0242 l:000241 d:000241 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-openid-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/open_id.rb:65
c:0044 p:0177 s:0239 b:0239 l:000238 d:000238 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:58
c:0043 p:0177 s:0235 b:0235 l:000234 d:000234 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:41
c:0042 p:0019 s:0231 b:0231 l:000230 d:000230 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30
c:0041 p:0241 s:0227 b:0227 l:000226 d:000226 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44
c:0040 p:0019 s:0223 b:0223 l:000222 d:000222 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30
c:0039 p:0241 s:0219 b:0219 l:000218 d:000218 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44
c:0038 p:0019 s:0215 b:0215 l:000214 d:000214 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30
c:0037 p:0044 s:0211 b:0211 l:000210 d:000210 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:30
c:0036 p:0015 s:0207 b:0207 l:000206 d:000206 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:1
c:0035 p:0093 s:0200 b:0200 l:000199 d:000199 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14
c:0034 p:0155 s:0193 b:0193 l:000192 d:000192 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24
c:0033 p:0046 s:0187 b:0187 l:000186 d:000186 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21
c:0032 p:0054 s:0182 b:0182 l:000181 d:000181 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182
c:0031 p:0027 s:0175 b:0175 l:000174 d:000174 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:1
c:0030 p:0015 s:0164 b:0164 l:000163 d:000163 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302
c:0029 p:0014 s:0156 b:0156 l:000250 d:000155 BLOCK  /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32
c:0028 p:0019 s:0154 b:0154 l:000153 d:000153 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cac
c:0027 p:0051 s:0150 b:0150 l:000149 d:000149 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12
c:0026 p:0019 s:0146 b:0146 l:000250 d:000250 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31
c:0025 p:0015 s:0142 b:0142 l:000141 d:000141 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connectio
c:0024 p:0029 s:0138 b:0138 l:001720 d:000137 BLOCK  /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46
c:0023 p:0155 s:0136 b:0136 l:000135 d:000135 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416
c:0022 p:0011 s:0126 b:0126 l:001720 d:001720 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44
c:0021 p:0015 s:0122 b:0122 l:000121 d:000121 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:106
c:0020 p:0049 s:0112 b:0112 l:000111 d:000111 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48
c:0019 p:0017 s:0108 b:0108 l:000107 d:000107 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47
c:0018 p:0027 s:0100 b:0100 l:000099 d:000099 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13
c:0017 p:0032 s:0096 b:0096 l:000095 d:000095 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17
c:0016 p:0052 s:0087 b:0087 l:000086 d:000086 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72
c:0015 p:0014 s:0083 b:0083 l:000077 d:000082 BLOCK  /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:11
c:0014 p:0019 s:0081 b:0081 l:000080 d:000080 METHOD <internal:prelude>:10
c:0013 p:0054 s:0078 b:0078 l:000077 d:000077 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:11
c:0012 p:0193 s:0073 b:0073 l:000072 d:000072 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30
c:0011 p:0032 s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/application.rb:168
c:0010 p:0021 s:0062 b:0062 l:000061 d:000061 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/application.rb:77
c:0009 p:---- s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 FINISH
c:0008 p:0015 s:0055 b:0055 l:000054 d:000054 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14
c:0007 p:0015 s:0050 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13
c:0006 p:0338 s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52
c:0005 p:0257 s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111
c:0004 p:0393 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD /Users/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70
c:0003 p:0126 s:0009 b:0009 l:001338 d:000008 BLOCK  /Users/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:---- s:0002 b:0002 l:000001 d:000001 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:106:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44:in `call!'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44:in `call!'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:41:in `call!'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-core-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:58:in `request_call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-openid-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/open_id.rb:65:in `request_phase'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/oa-openid-0.3.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/open_id.rb:70:in `start'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-openid-1.3.1/lib/rack/openid.rb:102:in `call'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rack-openid-1.3.1/lib/rack/openid.rb:123:in `begin_authentication'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer.rb:228:in `begin'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer.rb:243:in `begin_without_discovery'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:118:in `get_association'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:130:in `negotiate_association'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:196:in `request_association'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:331:in `extract_association'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/associationmanager.rb:45:in `extract_secret'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:40:in `xor_secret'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60:in `strxor'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60:in `zip'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60:in `each'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60:in `bytes'
/Users/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60:in `next'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010509451e rb_vm_bugreport + 110
1   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000104f88533 report_bug + 259
2   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000104f886a1 rb_bug + 161
3   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010508fea0 vm_call0 + 1248
4   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000105082f23 rb_iterate + 179
5   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010508306d rb_block_call + 45
6   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000104f81586 enum_zip + 294
7   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00000001050823e6 call_cfunc + 102
8   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000105086972 vm_call_method + 738
9   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000105089dce vm_exec_core + 11214
10  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010508deae vm_exec + 94
11  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010508fb83 vm_call0 + 451
12  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000105086fa2 vm_call_method + 2322
13  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000105089dce vm_exec_core + 11214
14  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010508deae vm_exec + 94
15  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00000001050871b1 rb_vm_invoke_proc + 161
16  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010509abdb thread_start_func_2 + 283
17  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000105097be4 thread_start_func_1 + 116
18  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff87b128bf _pthread_start + 335
19  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff87b15b75 thread_start + 13

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Which ruby version? Due to ruby bugtrack(http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/2311) this one was solved in release 1.9.2.

Comment: The output states 1.9.2p290 which is what I'm running and just ran into the same problem: versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/dh.rb:60: [BUG] cfp consistency error - call0
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]